# element with height 100% and overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow

What I basically need to achieve is to have an element (div, span, table, whatever) to consume 100% of its' parent height and show scrolls if it's content is taller.

The problem is, only chrome and IE in quirks work OK with `height:100%; overflow: auto;`. Firefox, Opera and IE in standards (any IE 7+, any "standards") just ignore the overflow and stretch the html element below the parent size. If I set fixed height it works, but I can't determine the available height before rendering, there are multiple possible values.

Simplified example ([jsFiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/KLQEp/)):

```
<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <table id='container'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id='element-in-question'>
                        <!--Content long enough to stretch the div-->
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td id='footer-cell'>
                <div id='footer'>I'm footer<div>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Css:

```css
#parent { height:500px; width:500px; position:absolute; }
#container { height: 100%; width:100%; }
#element-in-question { height:100%; width:100%; overflow: auto; }
#footer-cell { height:30px;}
#footer { height: 30px; }
```

In real app all this stuff runs in an iframe, table is used to render header and footer and so on. Please do not suggest stop using tables, it's legacy application with 100+ places that need attention. CSS only solution would be ideal.

One more point: it should work in Chrome, IE10 standards mode. FF, Opera and Safari are not supported, IE9 and below handled differently.

**Update**: there are about ten footers with different heights, ideally the solution should not depend on fixed footer height.

Comment: have you tried setting a max-height equal to the "parent" height on the "element-in-question" work?

Comment: @mhps, max-height does not work either

Comment: wait you say the issue is with firefox, opera, safari and IE < 9 but those browsers are not supported? So what's your issue?

Comment: @ryan The issue is in IE10.

Comment: Is javascript an option?

Comment: @Mute it is, but quite undesirable. The project is already overloaded with javascript "supposed-to-be-fix-for-the-bug" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/KLQEp/7/)

The problem is that `height: 100%;` is going to fill the next defined container. For whatever reason, tables aren't seen as a valid container for that purpose. So what we need to do is utilize some of the quirkiness of how tables are laid out.

```
position: absolute;
top:5px; left:5px;
right: 5px;
bottom: 40px;
overflow: auto;
border: 1px solid green;
background-color: #eee;
```

No need for relative positioning on the `td`.  Don't ask me why, perhaps someone more knowledgable than I can chime in.

Regardless, with this we can force it to expand to fill a set amount of space, while still allowing:

1. The footer to be visible.
2. The padding to be present (even if it's not *technically* padding.)
3. This solution to work in a cross-browser environment.

Really hope this helps; if it doesn't, I'd be more than happy to give it another shot.

---

**Update**

You said that javascript isn't how you'd like to do it, but here's a short solution using jQuery which would actually solve the problem:

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KLQEp/10/)**

```
$('td > div').each(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    var text = t.html();
    t.hide();
    t.height(t.parent().height());
    t.show(text);
});
```

**Why this works:**

The `div` needs its parent to have a defined height before 100% height works, however that's not an option for you as you've already stated that this is all dynamic content.  No problem.  We just need the jQuery to push the calculated height to the `div` after the browser has already rendered it.  Simple enough, right?

Well, not so fast.  Divs aren't meant to be bounded by table cells, at least not ideally.  We already have something that serves as a logical, separate container in the `td`, and the `div` doesn't much care what the `td`'s height is if it has a boatload of content that's spilling over its borders already. And when we go to query the height of that `td`, no matter what it *actually* is, it's going to report that it's larger than the elements which it contains.  So, if you look on the fiddle after commenting out the lines where we empty the `div`, you'll see that the `td` is erroneously reporting itself to be almost 900 pixels tall.

**So what do we do?**

Well, we take that content away from the `div`.  Now it's just a husk, and it's going to be smaller than its container in every circumstance.  That means that the `td` isn't going to <strike>lie about</strike> misreport its size when we query it, since it's confidently containing its children.

And once we get the truth from the TD, we tell the `div` that the size its parent has reported is the size that it needs to be, and give it back its content.

Voila.  You've got a `div` that **actually respects its parent** now.  If only real children were that easy.

Comment: That's one of the options I've tried. The problem is, the footer does not have fixed height. I haven't mentioned it in the question originally, updating. But that's loser to the desired result, thanks.

Comment: @J0HN How is the footer's height determined, then?

Comment: all those stuff are unique modal pages shown in popup iframe. What I mean by *footer* is technically just the bottom row. It's meant to be a footer, but on different pages different content is placed. Majority of pages have just Ok-Cancel buttons, but some have more complicated stuff, like the selected values, options to email, etc.

Comment: Well, if you could use jQuery/jabascript, this would be a breeze.  I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: @J0HN I've updated with an example of the jQuery working the problem effectively, if it's absolutely important it be CSS only, you're going to be fighting an uphill battle that may not be worth the struggle.

Comment: jQuery win eventually. The div respects its parent height, but the height of the cell is incorrect anyway (thats a well-known "cell 100% height" problem) :) So there were actually two independent issues. Btw, I've optimized your javascript a bit. :)

Comment: Ah, didn't even realize that it would work simply hiding the element.  Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

**The basic behavior of HTML tables**

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/HUCJm/) showing how small and extra-large content affects the width and height of a table. There are gray rulers alongside the tables, showing the intended dimensions of the tables. [Standalone version of the demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Matt_Coughlin/HUCJm/show/).

Scrolling extra-large variable-size content in a table cell appears to work to some extent vertically, and not at all horizontally.

For height, there are 3 different outcomes in different browsers:

1. The overall height of the table is correct. This occurs with Chrome and Safari (Webkit browsers).
2. The content row occupies the intended height of the overall table, and the footer row adds additional height to the table, causing the table to be a little taller than intended. This occurs with Firefox and Opera, and IE7/8/9/10 in Standards mode (though in IE, the footer cell is even taller than the height of the footer content, which adds significant extra height to the table).
3. The entire height of the content row is displayed with no scrollbars, causing the table to be much taller than intended. This occurs with IE7/8/9/10 in Quirks mode.

For width, the outcome is comparable to #3 for all browsers (the full content width is always displayed with no scrollbars).

**CSS compromise**

The closest to a CSS solution that appears to be possible is setting a fixed height for `#element-in-question` (though letting it remain scrollable), and allowing the footer to vary in height. The overall size of the table would vary by however much the different footers vary in height. If the height difference of the footers is small, or if it's not critical that the overall table always has the same height, then this may be a reasonable compromise.

The CSS posted in the question would look something like the following (giving `#element-in-question` whatever height is determined to be optimal, when combined with the average or most-common footer height).

```
#parent { width:500px; position:absolute; }
#container { width:100%; }
#element-in-question { height:450px; width:100%; overflow: auto; }
#footer-cell { }
#footer { }
```

Here's an [updated version of the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/WScx8/1/) posted in the question, using the changes listed above (tested in: IE7/8/9/10 Standards and Quirks mode, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera). If there are difficulties running JSFiddle in older versions of IE, try this [standalone version of the demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Matt_Coughlin/WScx8/1/show/).

The website design appears to go beyond the bounds of what HTML tables are capable of. Unless some constraints can be imposed upon the design (such as the one described here), it looks like this will require JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: thanks for thorough investigation. Horz scrolling work ok anyway. I've tested the fixed height approach among the first, even before asking here. There are two issues that does not allow using it: (1) the content of different height on different pages (legacy app, close deadline, no time to sort it out), (2) sometimes there are collapsible elements above or below the scroll area. Now I understand I should have mentioned it in the question, but by the time of posting I thought it's not so important, so sacrificed this for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a workaround for this.`tbody` tag is added automatically in firefox and that cause the problem. Add `height:100%` to your `td` and `height:90%` to your `tbody`. The `tbody` tag never existed so you should add it with css.

`table tbody{height:90%}`

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KLQEp/6/)

Comment: The footer is pushed below the parent element. So it's not an option, but thank you anyway.

Comment: So change your tbody height to 90%

Comment: That's not an option unfortunately, we can have footers and headers of different height, some of them collapsible, some fixed, and so on.

Comment: @J0HN Curious: why not? You're already using tables for layout, seems like you'd be willing to do just about anything.

Comment: @Chris, yes, you are right, but with one minor correction. I'm not willing to do anything, unless it works :) Setting fixed height as well as partial (90%, 80%, whatever) heights will work only in *some* cases. And, as I already said, I've got 100+ places that require attention, so it's just ridiculously high amount of Dev and QA work. So, thanks for suggestiong, but it wouldn't work.